# Пишет "Приложение не установлено" на планшете. На телефоне все ок

Tags: android

Скорей всего что-то с permission, но я все закомментил и все равно. Приложение уже удалил, ставлю новой - та же ошибка. На телефон ставится нормально и запускается тоже.

Кто-то сталкивался с данной проблемой?

Манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="lnk.iclient">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Код в студию. И шаги, чтобы воспроизвести проблему. Телепаты сегодня отдыхают.

Comment: ;)))) Весь приложения код или только манифест?)

Comment: То, что по вашему мнению достаточно для воспроизведения проблемы, разумеется.

Comment: Код обновил, не пойму, в чем проблема.

Comment: "Телепаты сегодня отдыхают." - Нет, я здесь. Просто отвлекся.

Comment: @Igor: Оставляю вас с тёзкой.

Comment: Спасибо обоим))))

Comment: проверьте `targetSdk`, `minSdk` , `maxSdk`. там какие значения стоят? И версия андроида у телефона и планшета какие?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 22
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 22
На планшете 4.4.2, на телефоне 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем убрал из build.gradle вот эти лишние сервисы и все встало:
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
     спасибо всем!

Comment: Возможно и с ними поднимется на планшете если вы установите/обновите сервисы на самом планшете.

Answer (score 0):

Подобное может произойти если:

1. На девайсе не включены настройки разработчика и не разрешён режим отладки.
2. Девайс не находится в режиме, позволяющем доступ к памяти (например находится в режиме зарядки)
3. В манифесте [запрещено](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24198553/3212712) устанавливать приложение на девайсы с большим экраном (`<supports-screens android:largeScreens="false" android:xlargeScreens="false"`)
4. `minSdkVersion` больше, чем `SDK` девайса.
5. В манифесте есть требование на доступ к датчикам, не имеющимся на девайсе. Например запрос на тачСкрин. Таки есть же, наверное, такие планшеты - без тача...
6. Битый кабель. Попробуйте другой. Да, бывает, что один кабель работает с телефоном и не работает с планшетом.

Comment: Дело в том, что на два разных планшета и на обоих не запускается. А на телефоне и эмуляторе все ок. И нюанс - раньше приложение становилось и работало)

Comment: @Igor, ну... откатывайтесь по коммитам в гите и смотрите когда и чего добавили...

Comment: В том и дело, что до гита я еще не дорос(